# No disk space on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I am new to Linux(Ubuntu), so please excuse my naivete. While dual-booting my computer (primary Windows 11), I allocated 150 GB, made a new disk for Linux, and booted Ubuntu onto it. But now, while using Ubuntu, I am getting this message that I have limited disk space available. Can anyone please help me? I am still trying to figure out why I am getting this message and how to fix it.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Your question as it is, is not answerable. [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1507278/edit) and add more information, such as which options you selected while installing Ubuntu. Did you select LVM, encryption, or any other advanced options? Or did you stick to the defaults? Please open the app "Disks" in Ubuntu. Select the disk where Ubuntu is installed on the left panel. Select the partition where Ubuntu is installed on the main window. Take a screenshot of the Disks app window. Add the screenshot to your question above along with the other information.